# Automatically setting standard Raster style when loading raster sets in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, style, rendering, transparency-opacity

For my project I work with a lot of raster data sets and when loading the data into QGIS they render with a white background which I would like to see transparent (no-data).

I also worked before with ArcMap and that had an option to set a standard Raster Layer rendering. Since I have hundreds of raster-files it is a bit tedious to set the style/transparency one-by-one.

Does anyone knows if QGIS has something similar?

Comment: You may load all rasters (drag & drop for example), then style one of them, copy the style, mark all other rasters and then paste the style. Suitable if you don't have to add rasters later on.

Comment: Your best bet is to write a pyqgis script that will load the raster into QGIS. Because the no data values of the raster layers can be different you need to identify each value, min and max values of the raster in order to correctly classify using  pyqgis. This is a relatively straight forward script